# About whom am I talking about?

Tags: riddle

I imagine a lot and sometimes I overlook the reality.

So here goes the riddle.

> Who can be bigger than the universe,
>
> and yet Who can be contained in a atom.
>
> Who can be as sweet as honey,
>
> and yet Who can be as sour as lemon.
>
> Who can be as almighty as the God,
>
> and yet who can be as devilish as the Satan.

**About whom am I talking about?**

Comment: Is "nothing" the intended answer? :p

Comment: no @AeJey. I would have never asked such a silly puzzle.

Comment: I know. I have seen some of your previous good quality questions before. And that's why asked it in comment :)

Comment: @prog_SAHIL   Is it "Desire" correct?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Also, I hope the intended answer is not - a lie/a metaphor/a pun/a mystery/unknown/ etc cause most of them fit here.

Comment: Is there a significance to capitalization and word usage specifically with respect to Who/whom and multiple "about" in the question?

Comment: @Forklift not the multiple "about" but yeah the capitalization of Who/whom is well intended and a few more things if you analyse deeply.

Comment: @Techidiot no it is not.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Thanks. And just to erase another possibility, it's not the word *Who* right?

Comment: @Techidiot Ahmmm I can't say. :p not the word, but the noun 'Who'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are about:

> Horton Hears a Who!

Bigger than the Universe, can be contained in an atom

> It's a planet in a speck of dust, clearly having indefinable size

Sweet and Sour

> The sour kangaroo incident is fixed with "Beezle" oil (sweet honey, presumably)

Almighty as God, devilish as Satan

> Horton carries around a planet. That's almighty, for sure. The speck in which the planet resides is stolen by and eagle and dropped into a cloverfield. That's rather devilish.

Maybe not a perfect match, but it feels right.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about

> The word/noun/pronoun - **Who**

Explanation

> I'm not sure if it's even valid, but it looks like the riddle is specifying a quality of the word *who* which as confirmed by OP in the comments is ment to be treated as noun.

Comment: Not the exact answer but you were close. +1 for the effort.